# python: queue issue on itertools.product

Tags: python, queue, python-itertools

```
import itertools
import Queue

cars = ["Chrysler", "Ford", "LeSabre", "Jeep", "pontiac" ]
colors = ["white", "green", "blue", "silver", "red"]

cars_q = Queue.Queue()
for car in cars:
    cars_q.put(car)
    print cars_q.qsize(), car

while not cars_q.empty():
    for comb in enumerate(itertools.product(cars_q.get(), colors)):
       print comb
```

> the script should do all combinations of cars-colors and with two
>   lists works fine but if I put a list on queue the output is:

```
(0, ('C', 'white'))
(1, ('C', 'green'))
(2, ('C', 'blue'))
(3, ('C', 'silver'))
(4, ('C', 'red'))
(5, ('h', 'white'))
```

> why queue take only the first char?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to put a tuple of car into cars_q.

```
for car in cars:
    cars_q.put(tuple([car]))
    print cars_q.qsize(), car
```

Comment: @marioLetterman 1. this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449184/python-converting-string-to-tuple-without-splitting-characters) may help understand how to convert string to tuple   2. a [tuple](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) is a sequence of immutable Python objects and cannot be changed unlike lists.

Answer (score 2):

Because you gave the result of `cars_q.get()` (which returns "Chrysler") to `itertools.product`, which then iterates over it: `"C", "h", "r"`...

Are you aware of what `Queue` is? Are you perhaps looking for `collections.deque`?