# Converting a list of words into tuple bound words

Tags: python-2.7, file, dictionary, tuples

I am taking a text file, importing and converting it to a list of strings. Then I am trying to make every unique word in to a key. I want them to be immutable or tuples. The problem I am having is the word is always split into characters. I found a [similar post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449184/python-converting-string-to-tuple-without-splitting-characters) but with no effect.

If someone could help me and explain where I am going wrong and why `tuple(word)` produces the same outcome as `tuple(word,)`.

```
with open(f, 'r') as f:
    clean_str = f.read().translate(None, string.punctuation).lower().split()
    key_dic = {tuple(word,): [] for word in set(clean_str)}
    return key_dic
```

file says: The cat chased the dog.

output for both:

```
{('t', 'h', 'e'): [], ('c', 'a', 't'): [], ('c', 'h', 'a', 's', 'e', 'd'): [], ('d', 'o', 'g'): []}
```

Comment: Strings are already immutable.

Comment: Yeah I was really tired, cant believe I said that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `tuple` is being used as a function, any terminating comma is being consumed by the function grammar rather than producing a tuple.

```
>>> tuple('foo')
('f', 'o', 'o')
>>> tuple('foo',)
('f', 'o', 'o')
>>> tuple(('foo',))
('foo',)
```

But you don't need to invoke `tuple()`:

```
>>> {('foo',) : 'bar'}
{('foo',): 'bar'}
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but the resulting tuple includes the terminating comma. Is there a way to produce a tuple for each word that doesn't include the comma?

Comment: No. Passing a sequence to `tuple()` results in a tuple with each element being an element of the original sequence.