# Python String Modification

Tags: python, string, parsing, tuples

I have a python tuple that contains items such as:

```
kone = ('ice_cream', 'sprinkles', 'toppings', 'nuts', 'cherries')
```

I'm trying to add that tuple to a command line call but the formatting is off. My current code looks like:

```
subprocess.popen("python", str(kone))
```

but will call this

```
 ('python',"('ice_cream', 'sprinkles', 'toppings', 'nuts', 'cherries')")
```

How can I edit my code so it returns just the content within "kone" instead:

```
 ('python','ice_cream', 'sprinkles', 'toppings', 'nuts', 'cherries')
```

Comment: `('python',) + kone` ?

Comment: Yep that works. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Variables to Tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380860/add-variables-to-tuple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
subprocess.popen(("python",) + kone)
```