# Inserting elements into a tuple at the time of running the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

An input of n integers is taken at the run time.
n integers are taken as input in a single line, separated by a space.
**We have to create a tuple of this n integers and perform hash(tuple) function** on it and give the output.

Comment: Use `input()` to input the line. That will give you a string. Use the string method `split()` to split the line on spaces. That you will give you a list. Call `tuple(mylist)` to turn the list into a tuple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Variables to Tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380860/add-variables-to-tuple)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is:

```
def your_homework():
    return hash(tuple([int(i) for i in input("give me n integers").split()]))
```