# Python list of tuples: increase number of tuple members

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples with the pattern "id", "text", "language" like this:

```
a = [('1', 'hello', 'en'), ...]
```

I would like to increase number of tuple members to "id", "text", "language", "color":

```
b = [('1', 'hello', 'en', 'red'), ...]
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: A tuple is immutable, so you have to create a new tuple.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Variables to Tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380860/add-variables-to-tuple)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a tuple is immutable you have to create new tuples. I assume you want to add this additional value to every tuple in the list.

```
a = [('1', 'hello', 'en'), ('2', 'hi', 'en')]
color = 'red'

a = [(x + (color,)) for x in a]
print(a)
```

The result is `[('1', 'hello', 'en', 'red'), ('2', 'hi', 'en', 'red')]`.

---

If you have multiple colors in a list with as many entries as you have in your list with the tuples you can `zip` both sets of data.

```
a = [('1', 'hello', 'en'), ('2', 'hi', 'en'), ('3', 'oy', 'en')]
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']

a = [(x + (color,)) for x, color in zip(a, colors)]
print(a)
```

Now the result is

```
[('1', 'hello', 'en', 'red'), ('2', 'hi', 'en', 'green'), ('3', 'oy', 'en', 'blue')]
```

Comment: What would be the correct syntax if color is a list with the same length as a?

Comment: @AndreyKazak I added an example for this use case.

Comment: Dear Matthias, kudos to you!

Comment: Can the example for color list be improved for handling the following case: a = [[('1', 'hello', 'en'), ('2', 'hi', 'en')], ('3', 'dd', 'fr'), ('4', 'hi', 'ger')], where the 1st element is not a tuple, but a list of two (or more) tuples? It it better to handle using for loop, but not list comprehension?

Comment: @AndreyKazak I added a code example for that.

Answer (score 1):

tuples are immutable so you cannot append().
If you want to add stuffs you should use python lists.
Hope, that might help you!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the tuple to a list, change it, and then converting back to a tuple

```py
a[0] = list(a[0])
a[0].append("red")
a[0] = tuple(a[0])
```

Just loop this for the entire list and it should work